# How disable internet connection of an azure virtual machine (administrator account)

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

I don't want internet connection in an azure virtual machine for a while (20 minuses). How can I do that?

Comment: Please see if this blog post helps: https://reticent.net.nz/prevent-internet-access-from-azure-virtual-machines/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using ACL and Network Security Group to block all incoming traffic, you can do that through PowerShell and use Azure Automation to run the script every specified time, you can have a look at the below link for more details

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/network-isolation-options-for-machines-in-windows-azure-virtual-networks/